# Software to auto adjust brightness of screen(s) from webcam

Tags: display, webcam, brightness

Does any windows software exist to auto-adjust the brightness of a monitor (laptop screen and external monitor) based on the amount of light that a connected webcam senses?

Comment: Not sure if such software exists but if its possible its a really good idea, seeing as most modern laptops have built-in webcams.

Comment: And the downvote / close is for what?  When this question was asked I don't believe the software recommendations stackexached was opened yet.  If you feel it is placed here in error please move it there instead of downvoting and voting to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was looking for the same thing, for now i only found this, doesn't work with camera, but with time, at least

http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/

Answer (score 2):

I've just done this tonight : http://calvin-studio.fr/projets.php?p=14 (in French)

Archive [here](http://calvin-studio.fr/data/archives/Lumi.7z) , with code + Visual project + executable.

Uses parts of redshift sourcecode, and escapi. So : Windows only, ugly console, never tested on dual display, probably messes with any software calibration tool, f.lux incompatible, Skype/MSN/any_videoconference_software-incompatible.

Works for me, though :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with running brightness adjustment every hour (using http://sven.killig.de/BLUntrl/) via the following autohotkey script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Loop
{
   Run, D:\autohotkey\BLUntrl.exe
     Sleep, 10000
     Send, {Esc}
     Sleep, 3600000
}
Return
```

This solution seems to work fine with f.lux.

Calvin's application from previous post is great, but it alters color balance on my monitors.

Answer (score -1):

"Many modern laptops include a built-in dedicated light sensor. If yours does, and if you're running Windows 7 Professional or higher, you can enable a Windows feature called "Adaptive Brightness" which will do what you want. Otherwise, click [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WebCam/SoftonEyes.shtml) and download "SoftonEyes"."